# When I use tablesorter, how can I copy the table header?

Tags: javascript, css, tablesorter

Just like the example of tablesorter on [this page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html), how can I copy the words in the header part of the table?

I try to change `unselectable="on"` to `unselectable="off"`, but it still don't work.

Comment: i don't think you can with this plugin. or you should modify the code in the JS. You should try this plugin [link](http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/) which you can select the header content

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But my project is now using the tablesorter, i don't want to change that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation it says you should use "cancelSelection" and turn it to false it should work than.

Description of "cancelSelection":

Indicates if tablesorter should disable selection of text in the table header (TH). Makes header behave more like a button. Default:true

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    cancelSelection:false
});
```

Comment: I change the plugin in my project, but thanks for your answer anyway. :)